# What is this ship?

Tags: battlefield-3

I was recently playing Battlefield 3 and came across this on the edge of the map, does anybody know what it is?

[image]

Comment: I would say it is just for scenery. I am guessing that the area you're looking at is out of bounds (you cannot walk over there).

Comment: That's crazy. It looks like an easter egg of some sort.

Comment: There's quite a lot of easter eggs in Bf3, including the dinosaurs and Faiths (from Mirrors' Edge) shoes and messenger bag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this link](http://stickskills.com/2013/03/05/dice-hints-at-battlefield-2143-reveal-in-end-game-dlc/) and the following video, it is, as Shotgun Ninja pointed out, an easter egg.

This particular easter egg is a reference to, or possibly teasing about, *Battlefield 2143*.

Comment: As 2143 hasn't been announced, it's purely speculative, but since there is a crate on Wake Island with 2143 stamped on the side...

Comment: oh please...oh please...